# Is there Tauriel in LotRO?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

Is there Tauriel the elven maiden and archer in LotRO? If so, where do you find her? If no, why not? I searched all or most of Felegoth (capital of the Woodlandrealm in the Eryn Lasgalen) but I didn't find her.

Comment: Tauriel is a non-canonical character invented just for The Hobbit trilogy, so if she's not there it could be for this reason. By the way, asking why a character is not included in a game falls under developer intent and therefore off-topic for Arqade.

Comment: @pinckerman Non-canonical shouldn't matter as e.g. Dorongúr Whitethorn isn't "canonical" either. Nor are Bregar, Toronn, Dolengyl, Brethilwen, Avorthal, Bregedúr and others.

Comment: Who knows, I'm speculating since I don't know the real answer. But that seemed relevant to me.

Comment: @ElytraRocketman problem is that the characters you mentioned were made up for the game. So, they are IP made by the game designers. Tauriel is a character in the Hobbit movies, so its IP is tied to the movies. As far as I know, LOTRO only has rights to use content from the books, not from the movies. That is why locations in the game are not made to look like the ones in the movies. Therefore, they can't legally use content that was specifically made up for the movies.

Comment: @SPArcheon I see, that is the reason. Why don't they have the rights? Weren't all of them bought by the Warner Brothers from Electronic Arts?

Comment: @ElytraRocketman probably.. cost efficiency? They were making a game based on the books with no direct competitor. They decided that  they didn't need to spend more money to get the rights to the movies too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, it does not appear that [Tauriel](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Tauriel) is in Lord of the Rings Online. The linked wiki mentions a few video game appearances, but LORTO is not one that is listed